# Can I add a regular expression into a .Net Assertion?

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I'm trying to pull out page source from a set of pages and run an assertion on the results, this is a Test that runs to check that we are crawling specific pages in our site.  Sometimes the results come back with a different case for the URL string, I'd like to account for that in the Assertion where I am checking page source.  This is probably the wrong way to do this but I was wondering if there is a way to add in the .Net regex commands to the Assertion text.  I have this as an assertion:

```
Assert.IsTrue(driver.PageSource.Contains("/explore"));
```

But is there a way to be sure that I can capture explore, Explore or EXPLORE?  I though I could use (?i) here but that doesn't seem to work.  I'm more used to Perl and it's regex capabilities but with C# and .Net I'm a little lost on where I can and can't use the inline regex commands.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Anthonys answer is valid, you don't really need regex. But if you do want to use it, you can use

```
Regex.IsMatch(driver.PageSource, "/explore", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
```

Comment: Thanks, I found this more readable with what I was trying to do and it is working for the cases I need:  Assert.IsTrue(Regex.IsMatch(driver.PageSource, "/explore", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase));

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a regular expression to perform a case-insensitive check. Use `IndexOf` and compare that the result is greater than -1. `IndexOf` has overloads that allow you to specify if casing matters. Something like

```
bool containsExplore = driver.PageSource.IndexOf("/explore", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) > -1;
Assert.IsTrue(containsExplore);
```

Comment: Very cool, I can see where I might need this in a few cases and don't think I would have ever come up with this

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
RegEx.Match("string", "regexp", RegExOptions.IgnoreCase).Success
```

Answer (score 1):

How about using

```
StringAssert.Matches(string, regex);
```

In your case, that would translate to

```
StringAssert.Matches("drive.PageSource", "\/explore");
```